# What is our policy on creating new tags?

Tags: discussion, tags, policy, tag-proposal

We should try to keep some order when it comes to tags. Do we already have an order? If not which rules do you suggest? Can I just create a tag if I feel that an important tag is missing?

Comment: Have you looked at [the existing Meta threads tagged with tag-proposal](https://stats.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tag-proposal)? This would give you some idea about current practice.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you have the reputation to reach the correct level of [privilege](https://stats.stackexchange.com/help/privileges) (which you do), then you can create tags.

However, with a mature site like this one, you're encouraged to think carefully about creating new tags (almost any tag of lasting value will either already exist or there will be a similar one which will compete with a new tag). If there's any doubt about how a possible new tag fits into the current tags, for example, you can always discuss it on meta.

Comment: Glen_b, can you kindly visit the dilemma [if we ought to create tag "dummy-variables"](https://stats.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4881/3277) and leave there a comment either con or pro?

Comment: @ttn I believe I went there 8 hours ago, and commented, and voted. (my comment is under amoeba's answer). Amoeba has been discussing it with me in chat as well.